# Predicting new data using sklearn after standardizing the training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using Sklearn to build a linear regression model (or any other model) with the following steps:

X_train and Y_train are the training data

1. Standardize the training data

   ```
     X_train = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
   ```
2. fit the model

   ```
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
   ```

Once the model is fit with scaled data, how can I predict with new data (either one or more data points at a time) using the fit model?

What I am using is

1. Scale the data

   ```
   NewData_Scaled = preprocessing.scale(NewData)
   ```
2. Predict the data

   ```
   PredictedTarget = model.predict(NewData_Scaled)
   ```

I  think I am missing a transformation function with `preprocessing.scale` so that I can save it with the trained model and then apply it on the new unseen data? any help please.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Take a look at [these docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html).

You can use the `StandardScaler` class of the preprocessing module to remember the scaling of your training data so you can apply it to future values.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                    [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
```

`scaler` has calculated the mean and scaling factor to standardize each feature.

```
>>>scaler.mean_
array([ 1. ...,  0. ...,  0.33...])
>>>scaler.scale_                                       
array([ 0.81...,  0.81...,  1.24...])
```

To apply it to a dataset:

```
import numpy as np

X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
new_data = np.array([-1.,  1., 0.])    
new_data_scaled = scaler.transform(new_data)
>>>new_data_scaled
array([[-2.44...,  1.22..., -0.26...]])
```

Comment: This is a useful answer -- I was wondering if the StandardScaler could also be used on the new unseen data. Great to see that's the case.

Comment: I think the that the argument for the `transform` function should be 2d array. In your case the `new_data` array is 1d.

Comment: but this would only work in the same session, right? is there any way to save the scaler for a later session, like you can save the model/weights of a trained neural network?

Comment: @J.Dahlgren did you get around by being able to save the scaler? I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: @Regressor If it's still relevant for you, here is a solution using the joblib package to export/import the standard scaler object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153373/11537601

Answer (score 7):

Above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782801/13332582) is OK when you have use `train data` and `test data` in single run...
But what if you want to `test` or `infer` after training

This will surely help

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data 

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X)
x = sc.transform(X)
#On new data, though data count is one but Features count is still Four
sc.transform(np.array([[6.5, 1.5, 2.5, 6.5]]))  # to verify the last returned output



std  = np.sqrt(sc.var_)
np.save('std.npy',std )
np.save('mean.npy',sc.mean_)
```

### This block is independent

```
s = np.load('std.npy')
m = np.load('mean.npy')
(np.array([[6.5, 1.5, 2.5, 6.5]] - m)) / s   # z = (x - u) / s ---> Main formula
# will have same output as above
```