# Saving StandardScaler() model for use on new datasets

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

How do I save the StandardScaler() model in Sklearn? I need to make a model operational and don't want to load training data agian and again for StandardScaler to learn and then apply on new data on which I want to make predictions.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#standardizing after splitting
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_std = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993565/save-minmaxscaler-model-in-sklearn

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you could use joblib **dump** function to save the standard scaler model.  Here's a complete example for reference.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target)

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_std = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
```

if you want to save the **sc** standardscaller use the following

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import dump, load
dump(sc, 'std_scaler.bin', compress=True)
```

this will create the file std_scaler.bin and save the sklearn model.

To read the model later use **load**

```
sc=load('std_scaler.bin')
```

Note: `sklearn.externals.joblib` is deprecated. Install and use the pure `joblib` instead

Comment: How to predict after loading the model data

Comment: use sc.transform(X) to apply the scaling to new data.

Answer (score 22):

Or if you like to pickle:

```
import pickle
with open('file/path/scaler.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(sc, f)
with open('file/path/scaler.pkl','rb') as f:
    sc = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Although, I would prefer using `with open()..` instead of relying the gc to close the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remember mean_ and scale_.

1. So after you fit (compute mean and scale) your StandardScaler, print out mean and scale.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print("Scaler mean: ", scaler.mean_)
print("Scaler scale: ", scaler.scale_)
```

In my example the output looks like this:
Scaler mean:  [ 9.52058421e-01 -6.98286619e-03 -4.14269899e-01 -1.40126971e-01
-8.17856250e+00  5.50322867e+01]
Scaler scale:  [ 0.6635306   0.29163553  0.65517668 23.05331473 36.66616542 43.53057184]

2. When you need you Scaler again, i.e for predicting (scaler1 is the new scaler to be sure not to use the old one):

```
scaler1 = StandardScaler()
scaler1.mean_ = np.array([ 9.52058421e-01, -6.98286619e-03, -4.14269899e-01, -1.40126971e-01, -8.17856250e+00, 5.50322867e+01])
scaler1.scale_ = np.array([ 0.6635306, 0.29163553, 0.65517668, 23.05331473, 36.66616542, 43.53057184]) 

# then use it to transform your data
X = scaler1.transform(X)
```

In my test the results where the same. Note: don't forget to set the commas in np.array([ ... , ...])

Cheers!

Comment: Please don't code this way and recommend it to others. It is a hacky solution that invites mistakes.

Comment: In Python, when a member variable contains an underscore, that means "don't touch it".

Comment: +1 Although avoiding the use of internal variables is a valid concern and warnings that this approach is dangerous are important (for example, mean_ and scale_ are not defined until you call fit_transform), this solution lets you recover the state of the StandardScaler without using external libraries or pickled files. It's unfortunate that there isn't a cleaner way for it...