# How to inverse transform models output?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning, sklearn-pandas

So I have a trained model, that was trained on a standardized dataset. When I try to use the model for testing on new data, that isn't in a dataset and that isn't standardized, it returns ridiculous values, because I can standardize the inputs, but I can't inverse transform the output as I did during training. What should I do?

Comment: Nvm, just found out that you can save your scaler for later use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152627/saving-standardscaler-model-for-use-on-new-datasets

Answer (score 0):

Use `sc.inverse_transform(predicted)`